# How to show a progress loader when ajax request sent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a ajax function to got data, when response will get meanwhile show a bootstrap progress loader(circle loader).

How to do this ?

Ajax Function JS:

```
$('#category_modal').click(function(event) {
     var url = $(this).data('url');
     var cid = $(this).data('id');
     $.ajax({
         url: '<?=$this->config->base_url()?>admin_panel/update_popup',
         type: 'post',
         data: 'id=' + cid
     }).done(function(data) {
         jQuery('#categoryModal .modal-content').html(data);
         $('#categoryModal').modal({
        "backdrop" : "static"
        });
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

animated icon can do the job. Also with css :

http://cssload.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can `progress-bar` class by jquery.

```
$('#category_modal').click(function(event) {
     /*here append your class to some element
       $(element).addClass("progress-bar");
     */
     var url = $(this).data('url');
     var cid = $(this).data('id');
     $.ajax({
         url: '<?=$this->config->base_url()?>admin_panel/update_popup',
         type: 'post',
         data: 'id=' + cid
     }).done(function(data) {
         /* when u r done remove
         $(element).removeClass("progress-bar");
         /*
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

add function

```
beforeSend: function () {
  // show loader
}
```

in your ajax call

Comment: $('#category_modal').click(function(event) {
     var url = $(this).data('url');
     var cid = $(this).data('id');
     $.ajax({
         url: '<?=$this->config->base_url()?>admin_panel/update_popup',
         type: 'post',                                                                                beforeSend: function () {
  // show loader
}
         data: 'id=' + cid
     }).done(function(data) {
         jQuery('#categoryModal .modal-content').html(data);
         $('#categoryModal').modal({
        "backdrop" : "static"
        });
     });
 });